# Data mining town and city names

Tags: maps, data-mining

I want to be able to create a full list of cities and towns for any given country.

I have been looking at the google maps api, but it seems to not be suited for the purpose given that it doesn't return enough results for a given query and a there is no way to ask for the "next" results for the query as far as I can tell. It is however clear that google maps does contain the information I am looking for, the matter is getting to it.

The source doesn't need to be google maps, of course. Bing maps etc could also be a possibility. Any ideas?

Comment: Try Yahoo Geoplanet its an amazing resource - http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/

Comment: This is extremely valuable information and don't expect good complete information for free, not even with datamining.

Comment: @nightcracker - Yeah I expected as much, and I'd expect them to actively prevent datamining of this type as well, which also seems to be the case for Google Maps.
@u07ch - Thanks, I wasn't aware of that one. I'll take a look if it is mineable.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the 'Postal Comapanies' web sites for each country contain downloaded Post Code/Zip tables.  This would be the easiest place to start searching.

http://www.foreign-trade.com/resources/country-code.htm  may also be a good start for some countries.

For Australia : http://auspost.com.au/products-and-services/download-postcode-data.html

Comment: Yahoo's Geoplanet covers 150 countries and about 6 million places... http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/

Comment: I would agree that is much better option that I wasn't aware of.  Google, MS and Yahoo etc are making more and more of this type of data freely available through their mapping ventures.  A few years ago, this type of data would have cost real money as per nightcracker's comment.